# Implement SecurityProtocolType.Tls, Tls11,Tls12 Ssl3 in WCF Routing Service

Tags: wcf, ssl, routes, web-config, tls1.2

I have a c# batch job that calls a 3rd party web service method to submit 
    data. The code works locally (Development machine), because of below line of 
    code and direct call ( no routing service in between) to the 3rd party 
    service.

Batch job Code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls 
                                         | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                         | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                         | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

when it is installed on server A (Batch Server) the call goes through WCF routing service B (Outbound router service)and then to external client service. Call doesn't get thru and throws exception "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Routing Service

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="routingData">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
     <routing routeOnHeadersOnly="false" filterTableName="routingTable1"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRoutingService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:02:00"/>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" sendTimeout="00:02:00">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="routingData" name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              name="reqReplyEndpoint"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRoutingService"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" />

    <endpoint address="ExternalService"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              name="ExternalService"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRoutingService"
              contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" />
  </Service>
 </Services>
   <client>
     **Modify address to the URL of the Internal Service**
    <endpoint name="ExternalWebReference.IJISBroker"                         
     address="https://3rdparty.ExternalWebReference.org:8443/IJISBroker
    /resources/Integrator/soapRequest" binding="basicHttpBinding"  
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="*">  
 </endpoint>
  </client>
   **FILTERS**
   <routing>
     <filters>
     <filter name="ExternalFilter" filterType="EndpointName"  
    filterData="ExternalService" />
   </filters
   <filterTables>
    <filterTable name="routingTable1">
      <add filterName="ExternalFilter"    
       endpointname="ExternalWebReference.IJISBroker" priority="0"/>
     </filterTable>
  </filterTables>
   </routing>
  </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

I have really tried almost everything but I keep getting below error, 
 so now I doubt If i need to add (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol)
 line of code to routing service. because the routing service have only 
 web.config , I am not sure how to integrate below in config or do I need 
 to write a custom router?

```
   **Exception Message :**
   Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

   Exception Message:  Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with  
   authority ‘3rdparty.ExternalWebReference.org:8443'.
     System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1
    [System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]
     Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 
    3rdParty.ExternalWebReference.org:8443'.
```

Do you think this issue can be caused by a routing service? If you've had any personal experience with this please share.